# Github readme file and icon links

Tags: github, icons, readme

A long time ago I made the readme.md on GitHub. I'm trying to remember where I found my icon links but I can't. It was a GitHub website with icons and links next to them.

For example, Instagram's link icon is this [link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/36131492/158049056-56e3a853-a309-4bc5-a85a-a03fa8e51ce8.png).

Does anyone know where to find these links? ;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising to me:

> Super Tiny Web Icons are minuscule SVG versions of your favourite logos. The average size is under 568 bytes!

The repo has been launched years ago. Could not find all the referenced items though. The logo images may have been changed.

Here's the link: https://github.com/edent/SuperTinyIcons

Why not just trying a new logo ;)